# Linking to the app's Store Page on WP7 using XNA

Tags: c#, url, store, windows-phone, xna-4.0

Is it possible for an XNA game/app to obtain it's own store link url through code or would I have to submit an app, wait for it's store link to become available and release an update including the store link?

Basically I want the player to be able to post his or her score to any social networks set up along with a link to the store page.

-Short question I know but my Google-Fu failed me this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a store URL, you will need to get hold of the app id.  This is done by calling GetManifestAttributeValue.  Note that the actual app id (Product ID) is generated when the app is published, and is different than the temporary one that is in WMAppManifest.xml.  This causes a chicken and egg scenario when it comes to testing this.

See this for detailed instructions:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Generating-a-Windows-Phone-9d19f939/

If all you need is to link to store from within your app, then use MarketplaceDetailTask to launch to the store.  Leave ContentIdentifier as null and it will attempt to bring up the detail page of the current app.  If you need to bring up the detail page of a different app, then you will need to know the app id, which you can only get after that app has been published.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394017%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: Would I be able to use it within a ShareLinkTask? That's how I'm going to be sharing the link

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question.  I thought your requirement was to be able to post a high score from within your app and also have a link (inside your app) to the store (to buy full version of game, etc.)  I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: The link you sent me worked perfectly, thank you :) I don't suppose you could also tell me how I can stop the user from changing the message when using ShareLinkTask could you? I don't want the player to be able to change the high score they post :P

Comment: Ah never mind, if you put the score as the link title the player can't change it :)